# YouTube API liveBroadcastContent field incorrect for stream

Tags: youtube-data-api

When I hit the video list endpoint on the YouTube API (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos), and pass a stream's id for in the "id" field, I always get back the following result for the liveBroadcastContent field:

```
"liveBroadcastContent": "none"
```

I am relying on this field to determine whether or not a video is a stream. But if this field does not return "live" for a stream which is live, I can't determine if the video is a stream. It is worth noting that the request is sent within a few minutes of the stream starting, so that may have something to do with it.

Is there a more reliable way to find out whether a YouTube video is a stream?